# Is there "all you can race" go-karting around Gold Coast, QLD, Australia?

Tags: amusement-parks

Does anyone know of any "all you can race" go-karting places in/near/around Gold Coast, Queensland?

I don't care if the conditions are hellish, for example: "this offer only applies during the graveyard shift (23:00 - 07:00)".

Comment: Do you mean "all you can race in a specific time"? In other words paying for your karting by the hour rather than by distance?

Comment: Here's one that offers "all you can race" for 100 minutes. https://gokartinggoldcoast.com.au/pricing/

Comment: Great point @DJClayworth; I guess I mean I want to pay by time, and for a sufficiently long time that one would be more likely to walk away from the track than reach the limit.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you could buy multiple 100 minute sessions and fulfill the requirements that way.

Comment: That doesn't really meet the spirit of this question.